# Omit JSON object properties by property name using JMESPath filters?

Tags: json, jmespath

I'm trying to get the keys of each checkout_data.flavors_sku property value except the prices property, but each filter/projection I've tried fails. How can the keys of nested properties except filtered properties be extracted? Also, is it possible to uses the values of one expression to query values stored elsewhere in an object?

### TL;DR

From this JSON,

```json
{
  "checkout_data": {
    "flavors_sku": {
      "Rich Milk Chocolate": { "1": ["530"], "6": ["296"] },
      "prices": {
        "530": "5.6",
        "296": "33.59",
        "529": "5.6",
        "297": "33.59",
        "531": "5.6",
        "299": "33.59",
        "532": "5.6",
        "301": "33.59"
      },
      "Classic French Vanilla": { "1": ["529"], "6": ["297"] },
      "Strawberry Sensation": { "1": ["531"], "6": ["299"] },
      "Variety Pack": { "10": ["532"], "60": ["301"] }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get these data:

*Result One:*

Keys of flavors_sku properties.

```json
[
  ["1", "6"],
  ["1", "6"],
  ["1", "6"],
  ["10", "60"]
]
```

*Result Two:*

Prices using the property values of checkout_data.flavors_sku objects except prices.

```json
[
  ["5.6", "33.59"],
  ["5.6", "5.6"],
  ["5.6", "33.59"],
  ["5.6", "33.59"],
]
```

Comment: What tools do you want to use? Python, jq, ... ?

Comment: @VladimirBotka, I need to use [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) queries.